# How to detect if a user's iCloud storage is full?

Tags: swift, storage, icloud

I've Googled for a while and still cannot find the answer.

In my app, there's a function to back up the data for a user. Here's the problem: even though a user's iCloud storage is full, one can still successfully back up. However, he/she shouldn't be able to back up when his/her iCloud is full.

What I want to ask is whether it is possible **to detect the remaining storage space in iCloud**.

Here is the backup code:

```swift
func save(data: Data, completion: @escaping (Result<Date, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let cloudURL = cloudURL else { // cloudURL: URL?
        completion(.failure(ChatBackupError.notAvailable))
        return
    }

    let document = ChatBackupDocument(fileURL: cloudURL) // ChatBackupDocument: UIDocument
    document.open { _ in
        document.data = data
        document.updateChangeCount(.done)
        document.save(to: cloudURL, for: .forOverwriting) { success in
            guard success else {
                completion(.failure(ChatBackupError.saveFailed))
                return
            }

            document.close { _ in
                guard let fileModificationDate = document.fileModificationDate else {
                    completion(.failure(ChatBackupError.saveFailed))
                    return
                }

                completion(.success(fileModificationDate))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you check  `try cloudURL.resourceValues(forKeys[.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey])`